# Cannot find records using redis_cli

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have Redis running in docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: my-redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD:-REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

My .env file has `REDIS_PASSWORD:redis_password`

I have an api that creates a record, no errors, but I cannot find the record using redis-cli.

I've tried `redis-cli -a redis_password` and `redis-cli` then 'auth redis_password`.

When I run `SCAN 0` or anything I don't see any records at all. Where are they being stored? I have no idea the data can be there but I can't access it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

By default `redis` contains 16 separated `DB` if you don't specify one when you push your data into redis `Key` then the database `0` is used by default
First connect to CLI using this command line

```
redis-cli -h <your_host> -p 6379 --user <your_user> --pass <your_password>
```

then enter the CMD

```
keys *
```

to show all keys in the DB if their is no data you will receive `(empty array)`  as message

Comment: Thanks, however it is still the same. I stop redis and I see a dump.rdb in the data folder. So it exists 'somewhere'. When I run keys * I get empty array